# How to get Output it showing no any error & output?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, authentication, controller

The contoller shows output error1 it does not shoe even row(),and does not give any error in developer tool. it get the file from ajax users_controller but does not work & issue is contant.

This is the form:

```
    <form class="form-signin" >
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
  <label for="name" class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus><br/>
  <label for="Password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
  <span class="error"></span>
</form>
```

These are the scripts:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').on('submit',function(){
            var username = $('#name').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'users_controller/login_check',
                data: {
                    username:'username',
                    password:'password'
                },
                success:function(result)
                {
                    if(result !== 'error')
                    {
                        window.location.href=result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $('.error').html('');
                    $('.error').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or password</p>');
                    $('.error').show(); 
                    }
                }
            }); 
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This is controller file:

```
public function login_check()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username',TRUE);
    $password = $this->input->post('password',TRUE);
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    //$row = $this->load->users_model('getUsers');
    $row = $this->users_model->getUsers($username,$password);

    if($row)
    {
        if($this->username === $username && $this->password === $password)
        {
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$row->user_id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$row->username);
        echo base_url('users_controller');
        }
        else
        {
        echo "error";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "error1";
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

The contoller shows output error1 it does not shoe even row(),and does not give any error in developer tool.

Comment: echo $username or  password to check it has values in controller

Comment: it is not the solution please be ethentic...

Comment: i am telling you to check these values are coming or not i know it is not an asnwer

Comment: the error is because your $this->users_model->getUsers($username,$password); is not returning any row

Comment: which in turn because your $username or $password are blank

Comment: ok this is quite helpful this is that i mean, why is not returning these values??

Comment: after echo they are coming without outputs and go to page that is not found....

Comment: i have returned my row in my users_model page

Comment: in ajax from the data part remove single quotes from username and password they are js `variable`

Comment: still not comming just go through the error1

Comment: show me getUsers() method

Comment: Class Users_model extends CI_Model{
  
 function getUsers($username,$password){
  
  $this->load->database();
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('username',$username);
  $this->db->where('password',$password);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  return $query->row();
  
  }
 }